# Can't get Ubuntu to see FTDI cable for breadboarding Arduino project

Tags: arduino-uno, ftdi

I am in the process of breadboarding an Arduino for a project and am using my FTDI Serial cable [Adafruit FTDI Cable](http://www.adafruit.com/products/70) (tested working on Windows 7). I have also tested the breadboarded Arduino successfully on Win7.

When I plug the FTDI Serial cable into my Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 with Mint Desktop) laptop and the other end to my project (exactly as I did for Windows and it works for Win7), the Tools, Port is grayed out when in Linux.

I have tried running Arduino as root, with no success.

The output of : dmesg | tail is

```
sudo dmesg | tail
[  729.069015] usb 4-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2,     SerialNumber=3
[  729.069019] usb 4-1.2: Product: TTL232R-3V3
[  729.069022] usb 4-1.2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  729.069024] usb 4-1.2: SerialNumber: FTF50VXW
[  729.487689] usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  729.615330] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
[  729.615384] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  729.615432] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  729.621997] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
[  729.622057] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
```

When I type "lsusb" into the terminal, there is no difference between when the FTDI is plugged in and not plugged in.
I have tried switching ports with no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a `/dev/ttyUSB0` file entry with the cable plugged in?

Comment: If it is not in the lsusb output, there should not be a device node - if there is, it is not connected to anything.  By appearances, the USB connection has failed after briefly being recognized - try a different port, try it with the logic end of the cable not connected to anything, try it with a hub or without one if you were using one.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the driver is loaded, in Terminal type:

```
lsmod | grep  ftdi_sio
```

If you get no answer then it's not loaded, load it using:

```
sudo modprobe ftdi_sio
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: lsmod | grep ftdi-sio
shows that the driver is already loaded.

Comment: lsmod | grep ftdi-sio
shows that the driver is already loaded.

The device is appearing in the /dev/ folder

Now when I try to upload code I get a avrdude out of sync error. I have confirmed I have the correct device (UNO) selected. As the Arduino is breadboarded, I press the reset button just as compilation completes (I use this same timing successfully when downloading from my Win7 machine).